# Batch file,executing second command if first command exit

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file, `updatesipversion.bat` that is calling another batch file, `template.bat`.

**`updatesipversion.bat` code:**

```
set init=empty
set main=svn propget svn:externals ./3c > install\msbuild\SipBranchDefaultDetailsTemplate.txt 
set error=update
set action=empty

call template.bat "%init%" "%main%" "%error%" "%action%"

set init=empty
set main=install\msbuild\SipBranchDetails.exe
set error=update
set action=empty

call template.bat "%init%" "%main%" "%error%" "%action%"
```

**`template.bat` code**

```
set /a WAcounter=0
for %%a in (%*) do set /a WAcounter+=1
if not %WAcounter%==4 goto :Error
set WAinit=%1
set WAmain=%2
set WAerror=%3
set WAaction=%4
set /a WAcounter=0

:WAinitCommand
IF NOT %1=="empty" %WAinit:~1,-1%

:WAmainCommand
set /a WAcounter+=1
IF NOT %2=="empty" %WAmain:~1,-1%
if %errorlevel%==0 goto :WASuccess

:WAerrorMsg
IF NOT %3=="empty" echo ERROR in %WAerror:~1,-1% Trying again......
if %WAcounter% equ 10 goto :Finish 
goto :WAmainCommand

:WASuccess
IF NOT %4=="empty" %WAaction:~1,-1%
exit

:Finish
exit 

:Error
echo there must be 4 command line arguments
exit
pause
```

When the `for` command in first call to template.bat call `if %errorlevel==0%` then it exits
from `:WASuccess`, if not it exits from `:Finish`.

The second time template is not called or other command are not executed.

Please tell me if first command is exited, how to continue with making second template call.

Thanks

Comment: for readability can you please edit your post and make the code parts lokk liek code?

Comment: Note that you can use `%~1`, etc. to automatically strip the quotes which would make the rest of that batch much easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

You should use either `start` instead of `call`, or use `exit /B` or `goto :eof` from your called batch. See [this for reference](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/exit.php).

Comment: Good point on `exit /b` or `goto :eof`. The part about `start` is nonsense, though, unless they want to run `template.bat` asynchronously.